# How can I inspect the source compiled from JSX when debugging a react app?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, babeljs, google-chrome-devtools

[This blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/02/21/how-to-get-and-debug-converted-source-code-in-react/) describes a way of viewing the result of the JSX transform when stepping through a react application, but it's a bit outdated (uses the old `ReactDom.render()` api loaded via a `text/babel` script). When using a clean copy of a react app generated from create-react-app (React@18.2.0 & babel@7.23.3) it doesn't seem there is a `transform.run` in the call stack that I can use to inspect the compiled source.

Is there still a way to do something like this with current react/babel versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable javascript source maps under browser developer tools settings.
Then when you debug you will see the compiled source code.

Answer (score 0):

For every JSX file, there is a main.xxxxx.js file generated under **Sources** -> right side tab.

[image]